# Do I need to submit sitemap.xml to google if I already have it in robots.txt and hosted on S3?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, sitemap, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have a static site hosted on S3 bucket which will have a robots.txt at root directory level.

This robots.txt file will have reference to my sitemap.xml file which is hosted on another S3 bucket. It is hosted on another S3 bucket because sitemap.xml is generated and updated automatically everyday, so it wouldn't mess with the CI/CD flow of the main site's S3 bucket.

My questions is:

Since sitemap.xml is on another s3 bucket domain, will that be an issue for crawlers as I read somewhere that sitemap.xml needs to be on the same domain as the main-site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick test I have made, it is impossible to serve google (via Google Search Console) a sitemap for a certain domain from another domain (unless in the robots.txt). If you were my client I would recommend (highly insist) that you add a sitemap.xml to your domain. You have to make it as easy as possible for crawlers to find your sitemap and go around your site.

Best of luck!

Comment: So as long as I have reference to Sitemap file in my robots.txt file, even if sitemap is hosted on another S3 bucket, Google will be able to make use of it? I can't submit the sitemap in Google Search Console to get insights obviously, but from SEO-ranking perspective it should be fine ?

Comment: In my opinion, with an emphasis on opinion, I think you should be ok. However, I have never done it this way, nor have I heard of someone who did (for the better or worse). Simply technically speaking, I THINK it should be alright. In addition, as far as I know, Google does not penalize sites without sitemaps (it just might not be able to crawl it efficiently).